# iTunes Connect 'Contains Encryption' for Facebook SDK and Flurry

Tags: ios, encryption, app-store-connect

I was wondering if anyone knew if the following frameworks/libraries contain encryption:

- Facebook SDK
- Flurry 4.3.2 library

Uploading a new version of my app to iTunes Connect and seen the question re: 'Have you added or made changes to encryption features since your last submission of this app?'

Cheers, Charlie

Answer (score 2):

I think the latest Flurry library (5.2.0) does use encryption, at least it uses keychain.  Flurry requires that you include the Security framework now.  I had a bunch of keychain related symbols that were undefined until I added the Security framework.  But I don't know if using keychain counts as using encryption so I answered NO when uploading.  I'll find out what happens.

Comment: Yeah I am now having to add Security framework but I am worried that might mean the app does contain encryption...

Answer (score 1):

No, these libs don't contain encryption. I've used the same libs and set "NO" for this question. As result app was approved without any issues.

Comment: Hi there - thanks so much for the responses. I dont suppose you know of any sections of the facebook websites or flurry websites that confirm this?

Comment: I don't think that such kind of information will be provided on Facebook or flurry web site. Encryption is very specific functionally and web sites will contain info about it only in case if it's products implement this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

No, none of them has any encryption. I also use them for a long time without any issues and I always tell Apple that my app doesn't have any encryption.

Comment: Hi there - thanks so much for the responses. I dont suppose you know of any sections of the facebook websites or flurry websites that confirm this?

Comment: By experience I know that there is no encryption. I've been doing this for years.